# Docu Sign Rest API Sender View Issue for in Process Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to use embedded signing to display the **sender** view in iframe.
If an envelope has 2 signers and one of them have signed the envelope we want to display the current state of the envelope to the sender.

Is there any API available to display current state of envelope to the sender.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "display current state of the Envelope" ? Do you want to display the (current state of) Documents in the Envelope?  Do you want to show audit trail info for the Envelope (who has signed, when, etc.)?  Something else?  It's true (as Ergin says in the answer below) that it's not possible to launch the DocuSign "Embedded Sending" view for an in-process (i.e., already Sent) envelope. But, there are likely other API call(s) that can give you what you need. Please update your question to be more specific about what you want to show the Sender, & I'll answer.

Comment: Hi Kim. Yes I want to display something similar to Audit Trail info for the Envelope i.e. which signer has signed. I checked iodocs.docusign.com but not able to figure out the exact API call for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment that you've added to your answer, the simplest way to retreive current status of all recipients for an Envelope is the **GET Recipients** API call:

```
GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?include_tabs=false&include_extended=false
```

The response will contain an array of recipient objects for each recipient type, and each recipient object has a **status** property that indicates the current status of the recipient.  For example, here's a response for an Envelope that contains 2 Signers -- the first has Completed signing, the second has not (status=delivered):

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "signInEachLocation": "false",
            "name": "Abby Adams",
            "email": "abby@outlook.com",
            "recipientId": "04cdba57-5383-4917-9081-e9dad16ba8a9",
            "recipientIdGuid": "04cdba57-5383-4917-9081-e9dad16ba8a9",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "1860fbdc-96ee-4d14-8353-c0213cd2728f",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "roleName": "Signer 1",
            "status": "completed",
            "signedDateTime": "2014-04-24T14:00:10.5800000Z",
            "deliveredDateTime": "2014-04-24T13:59:35.2330000Z",
            "templateLocked": "false",
            "templateRequired": "false"
        },
        {
            "signInEachLocation": "false",
            "name": "Adam Smith",
            "email": "adam@outlook.com",
            "recipientId": "fb3708f5-552f-410e-8029-9abbb5214196",
            "recipientIdGuid": "fb3708f5-552f-410e-8029-9abbb5214196",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "ecd6f430-5c08-4a4c-876e-ba7ad95f13dc",
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "status": "delivered",
            "deliveredDateTime": "2014-04-24T14:00:28.1930000Z"
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "recipientCount": "2",
    "currentRoutingOrder": "2"
}
```

If you need more detailed audit trail information, you can use the **GET Audit Events** API call:

```
GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/audit_events
```

The Response to this request will contain an array of **auditEvent** objects.  Each **auditEvent** object is composed of a single property -- **eventFields** -- which is an array of name/value pairs.

For example, the following response shows that Mary Smith created the envelope and sent the envelope, and then John Doe viewed the envelope and declined the envelope:

```
{
    "auditEvents": [
        {
            "eventFields": [
                {
                    "name": "logTime",
                    "value": "2014-05-23T03:07:52.7741974Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Source",
                    "value": "api"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserName",
                    "value": "Mary Smith"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserId",
                    "value": "bc266e97-83a6-472c-XXXX-ebad10e4cc6a"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Action",
                    "value": "Registered"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Message",
                    "value": "The envelope was created by Mary Smith"
                },
                {
                    "name": "EnvelopeStatus",
                    "value": "created"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ClientIPAddress",
                    "value": "XX.XX.XX.XXX"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Information",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "GeoLocation",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Language",
                    "value": "english (us)"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "eventFields": [
                {
                    "name": "logTime",
                    "value": "2014-05-23T03:07:53.6321919Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Source",
                    "value": "api"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserName",
                    "value": "Mary Smith"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserId",
                    "value": "bc266e97-83a6-472c-a25b-ebad10e4cc6a"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Action",
                    "value": "Sent Invitations"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Message",
                    "value": "Mary Smith sent an invitation to John Doe [john@outlook.com]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "EnvelopeStatus",
                    "value": "sent"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ClientIPAddress",
                    "value": "XX.XX.XX.XXX"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Information",
                    "value": "John Doe [john@outlook.com]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "GeoLocation",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Language",
                    "value": "english (us)"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "eventFields": [
                {
                    "name": "logTime",
                    "value": "2014-05-23T03:12:17.9412976Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Source",
                    "value": "web"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserName",
                    "value": "John Doe"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserId",
                    "value": "03c8a856-c0ae-41bf-943d-ac6e92db66a8"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Action",
                    "value": "Viewed"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Message",
                    "value": "John Doe viewed the envelope [documents:(Mutual NDA with anchors.pdf)]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "EnvelopeStatus",
                    "value": "sent"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ClientIPAddress",
                    "value": "XX.XX.XX.XXX"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Information",
                    "value": "John Doe viewed the envelope [documents:(Mutual NDA with anchors.pdf)]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "GeoLocation",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Language",
                    "value": "english (us)"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "eventFields": [
                {
                    "name": "logTime",
                    "value": "2014-05-23T03:12:30.3432181Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Source",
                    "value": "web"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserName",
                    "value": "John Doe"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserId",
                    "value": "03c8a856-c0ae-41bf-943d-ac6e92db66a8"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Action",
                    "value": "Declined"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Message",
                    "value": "John Doe declined the envelope [Reason: I changed my mind.]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "EnvelopeStatus",
                    "value": "declined"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ClientIPAddress",
                    "value": "XX.XX.XX.XXX"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Information",
                    "value": "Reason: I changed my mind."
                },
                {
                    "name": "GeoLocation",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Language",
                    "value": "english (us)"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The DocuSign REST API Guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf) contains information about both of the API calls.

**--- UPDATE ---**

You can retrieve an Envelope's document(s) at any time (i.e., regardless of signer/envelope status) by using the "**GET Envelope Documents**" API request:

```
GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/documents/combined
```

The response will contain a byte stream that represents the contents of the Envelope document(s) in PDF format -- your application can then simply write that byte stream to the browser to display the document(s).  See page 177 of the REST API Guide for details about this operation.

Regarding your question about customizing the "Embedded Sender View" -- it's not possible to customize the Sender view via the API -- i.e., an 'embedded Sender will always have the ability to do everything that they'd be able to do if sending directly via the DocuSign web console.

Comment: Hi Kim..thanks for your detailed response. I am however looking to get the document in this state i.e. one signer signed. Is it possible to view the Envelope in this state. Also can the sender view for Draft Envelope be customized?

Comment: I've added this info to my answer.  If my answer successfully addresses your question, please mark it as "accepted" so that others may benefit from the info in the future...thanks!

Comment: Thanks Kim for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Once a DocuSign envelope is in progress (meaning it has been sent and is NOT in draft state) then you can not generate the sender view.  The sender view is used to tag the envelope, and if the envelope has already been sent then no more tagging is allowed.

So to answer your question, no it's not possible to generate a *sender* view on a sent envelope, it's only possible to generate a *signing* URL at that point, and you can only generate the signing URL for recipients who have their `clientUserId` property set.

More on Embedded Signing here:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign

Comment: Hi Ergin thanks for your response. But when an envelope is in progress and we are making the following API call "v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:envelopeId/views/sender" the URL is being returned from Docusign. Why is the API returning a valid response when sender view cannot be shown for this type of Envelope. Also I have another query, when an Envelope is in draft state and we are showing the sender view using the above API is it possible to customize the View (hide some sections) shown to the user. Thanks for your help.